# CASE statement fails with data conversion error

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a integer column in which i need to add a case statement to display in a report. If that int column = -1 , the data in that column should be DOWN else the int value / 100

If i try like below

```
CASE WHEN LOADVALUE = -1 then 'DOWN'

ELSE LOADVALUE/100 END
```

As expected, i'm receiving an error : Error converting varchar to int. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `case` make sure, the datatypes in `when` clause and `else` clauses are consistent.

```
CASE WHEN LOADVALUE = -1 then 'DOWN'
ELSE cast(LOADVALUE/100 as varchar) END
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast your `ELSE` result to a `VARCHAR`

```
CASE WHEN LOADVALUE = -1 THEN 'DOWN'
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), LOADVALUE/100) END
```

Something you should keep in mind though, is that since the datatype of `LOADVALUE` is an `INT`, you may get unexpected results due to integer division.  You may want to consider using this instead:

```
CASE WHEN LOADVALUE = -1 THEN 'DOWN'
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), (LOADVALUE * 1.0)/100.0) END
```

This will convert the `LOADVALUE` to a decimal to correctly do the division.
(Please disregard this alternative if you are actually wanting integer division)

Comment: I don't believe you need the * 1.0 bit.  but you would definitely need the / 100.0 bit if you wanted a non integer result that was suggested by Siyual.  And if you were really that worried then you could simply do (LOADVALUE * 0.1)